# Video lens missing after upgrade to 12.04

Tags: upgrade, 12.04, lenses

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The video lens in unity is not showing up](https://askubuntu.com/questions/128803/the-video-lens-in-unity-is-not-showing-up)

I did an upgrade from 11.10 to 12.04 and after this process I saw that the dash was missing my lens for movies and online TV shows. I have the latest version of Unity (5.8). Even after entering `unity --reset` I did not get anything.

One solution is to do a fresh install of 12.04, but I have many settings that will take a long time to reset. What can I do?

Comment: Your solution worked!I installed the package and now the problem is solved.Thanks!

Comment: @valyum I was merely checking whether you actually had the package installed, but I guess that fixed it, lol. I posted my comment below as an answer since it fixed the issue for you; please don't forget to accept it.

Answer (score 4):

The issue is that you do not have the `unity-lens-video` package installed. Get it either from the Ubuntu Software Center or by running `sudo apt-get install unity-lens-video` in a terminal.