# The video lens in unity is not showing up

Tags: lenses

I recently upgraded from ubuntu 11.10 to 12.04 lts. the unity launcher dosent show the video lens.

Answer (score 3):

Its worth checking that the video lens package has actually been installed.

Try the following in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install unity-lens-video
```

Logout and login and examine your dash.