# My default home lens changed after upgrading. Is that normal?

Tags: unity, 12.04, unity-dash, lenses

After I upgraded to 12.04 from 11.10, my Home Lens (the default lens when you press super key) seems broken. It no long shows default six big icons that were there previously in 11.10, but instead seems to show the Apps lens.

Why is this? Is it a bug?

Comment: Hi, welcome to AskUbuntu. Please avoid asking two questions in one post. The answer the video lens question you asked is http://askubuntu.com/questions/128803/the-video-lens-in-unity-is-not-showing-up/128806#128806.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The new style Dash is the default in 12.04:

[image: Screenshot of Dash Home, showing three sections "Recent Apps", "Recent Files", and "Downloads"]

User testing showed that the old 11.10 dash confused new users and IMHO - really was not as useful as it could have been.

You have direct access to the different lenses by right-click of the dash icon:

[image: Screenshot of Dash icon's quicklist, showing links to different lenses]